# C# Setting up a single key hotkey

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to set a single key as global hook. Howerver, I was perhaps wondering if it's possible to manipulate this code, so that a single button is set as a global hot key?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        const int B = 0x42;
        const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004;
        const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, B + MOD_SHIFT, (int)Keys.X);
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2, B + MOD_SHIFT, (int)Keys.Y);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Hotkey X pressed.");
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 2)
                MessageBox.Show("Hotkey Y pressed.");
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "single button"?

Comment: So that a single key is pressed.

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is. Does the code not work? Do you want it to work differently?